# Javascript with radio selections not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Am I missing something? The button is supposed to launch the various sites based on the radio selection

```js
  
function navigateSite(){
  var getUrl = document.querySelector('input[name = "myRadio"]:checked').value
  console.log(getUrl);
}
```

```html
 <INPUT TYPE="radio" id="Orange" name="myRadio" value="www.google.com"> Orange
 <INPUT TYPE="radio" id="Apple" name="myRadio" value="www.mozilla.com"> Apple
 <INPUT TYPE="radio" id="Mango" name="myRadio" value="www.microsoft.com"> Mango
 <button onclick="navigateSite()">Select</button>
```

Comment: so what is the issue other than you had the snipplet set up wrong? You are not navigating so not sure how it it supposed to go there.....

Comment: There is a code master called Google : p https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Answer (score 1):

Popup Will only work outside the code snippet

```js
  
function navigateSite(){
  var getUrl = document.querySelector('input[name = "myRadio"]:checked').value
  console.log(getUrl);
  window.open(getUrl, getUrl, "width=600,height=500");
}
```

```html
 <INPUT TYPE="radio" id="Orange" name="myRadio" value="www.google.com"> Orange
 <INPUT TYPE="radio" id="Apple" name="myRadio" value="www.mozilla.com"> Apple
 <INPUT TYPE="radio" id="Mango" name="myRadio" value="www.microsoft.com"> Mango
 <button onclick="navigateSite()">Select</button>
```